# How to set right alignment for a selected item of DropdownButtonFormField with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `DropdownButtonFormField` with Flutter like this:

```
                  DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "My Label",
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
                    ),

                    items: ["No", "Yes"].map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(label),
                      value: label,
                      )).toList(),

                    onChanged: (value) {
                      ....
                    },
                    value: "No",
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  ),
```

which generates:

[image]

However the `No`/`Yes` values are displayed with a left alignment. Is it possible to display them on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can trick the UI using [`selectedItemBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/selectedItemBuilder.html)  and [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) on top of `DropdownButtonFormField`.

```dart
 LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
   //....
    selectedItemBuilder: (c) => ["No", "Yes"]
        .map(
          (e) => SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxWidth - 24, //-default dropDownIconSize
            child: Text(
              e,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList(),
   //....
```

[image]

Comment: how do you set the required field `items` for `DropdownButtonFormField`?

Comment: I think I didn't change anything else; `textWidthBasis` is not needed. Do you face any issue? and `["No", "Yes"]` sequence must be same as `items`

Comment: your solution works :) but it is a bit "complicated" for the only purpose of putting the visualisation on the right. Also there is this "items" duplication behaviour too. Just waiting if there are any other alternative solutions. If not I will fall back on this.

Comment: I agree but `selectedItemBuilder` is used for to build selected items and I could not find any simpler alternative.